# Sending my app a command in Cortana just searches Bing for my query string

Tags: win-universal-app, cortana

I am writing a Cortana "background app", and trying to call it from Cortana. Here is my VCD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.2">
  <CommandSet xml:lang="en-us" Name="MinimalCommandSet_en-us">
    <AppName>Mini</AppName>
    <Example>test foo</Example>

    <Command Name="TestCommand">
      <Example>test foo</Example>
      <ListenFor>test foo</ListenFor>
      <Feedback> Testing... </Feedback>
      <VoiceCommandService Target="VoiceCommandService"/>
    </Command>
  </CommandSet>
</VoiceCommands>
```

I go and type "Mini test foo" in Cortana, but it just searches Bing for "Mini test foo". How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not be taking a "deferral", which signals to the OS that your app shouldn't be terminated just yet. Remember to call `taskInstance.getDeferral()`, and hold on to the resulting object until your app finishes handling the Cortana request.